# Why are many properties in WPF an 'Object' instead of an interface?

Tags: wpf

I may be missing something about the fundamentals of WPF design, but I was wondering why many properties on WPF controls are exposed as the type 'Object'?

For example, MenuItem.Icon is an Object, and so is MenuItem.ToolTip. As a near first time user, this was very confusing to me (it felt like I was using a dynamic programming language, having no idea whether setting ToolTip to a String type would even work or not). Moreover, I tried to set the Icon to a 'System.Drawing.Icon' and I get an ArgumentException of "Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Icon." Shouldn't the property be typed so it can at least describe what in the world you're supposed to give it?

Honestly, my guess as to the reason is because you cannot implement an interface on a type you did not create (without creating a wrapper), but that's just a guess.

Thanks very much for your answers and insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason in my opinion is that since an [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) is the "ultimate base class of all classes in the .Net Framework". This gives you flexibility, in WPF you are not limited to a predefined type. Wpf is different and has a learning curve, but it does give you a lot more options to create a product that looks good.

i.e.

You can assign a TextBox to a ToolTip:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Text = "Hello World";
this.ToolTip = tb;
```

a Bitmap

```
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri((@"C:\Temp\20100706.jpg")));
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = myBitmapImage;
this.ToolTip = image;
```

and assigning a Image to a MenuItem

```
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri((@"C:\Temp\20100706.jpg")));
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = myBitmapImage;
menuItem1.Icon = image;
```

Comment: I do think that's cool, but doesn't the object have to be some sort of UI element? Both TextBox and Image are FrameworkElements. The only thing I've seen that you can assign that isn't a FrameworkElement is a String... is that really the only thing? If so it seems like not a good reason for it to be 'Object' as I could just create a Label or wrapper around my String.

Comment: @Rovert No,  it depends on the property, if there is a visual aspect to it and a way for WPF to convert it to an Image then it will be shown. You can assign *anything* to an object. I believe it is a by product of the [TypeConversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx) needed to make Xaml markup work.

Comment: Interesting point about the TypeConversion. That actually makes a lot more sense as to how and what it decides it can show. For example, looking to ImageSource to figure out how they work lead to a huge confusion, but now I know there must be some dynamic behavior going on behind the scenes. Thanks!

Comment: Part of this concept is. In many cases where WPF allows you to pass an object, wpf is flexible enough to know "This is an actual control i can display" or "this is a type i don't know, but i will try to find a DataTemplate that knows how to visualize this". Examples of this are ItemsControl and ItemTemplate, ContentControl and ContentTemplate. There are a couple more cases where this applies.

Comment: So that's what DataTemplates are for!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the `ToolTip` for example. A ToolTip is a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx), which **can contain any type of CLR (Common Language Runtime) object** (such as a string or a DateTime object) or a `UIElement` object (such as a Rectangle or a Panel). This enables you to add rich content to controls such as Button and CheckBox.

For this reason, elements such as `ToolTip` are exposed as `Object`, that is the root of the type hierarchy (with resulting ease of use, flexibility and clarity of the code).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine these properties were typed as *UIElements* (or some other WPF specific object). How would you add objects to your controls that were not *UIElements*?

You would have to provide a wrapper derived from a WPF object that exposes the information you require. Most of the time the wrapper would simply call *ToString()* of the object being wrapped. Seeing as most types you will be using provide a good enough default implementation of *ToString()* it makes sense to just call this instead of making the developer write wrappers for everything.

Second, imagine if they were typed as some interface. What if you want to communicate something that this interface can't? The only options are (a) the developer lives with the limitations of the framework or (b) Microsoft updates the interface and breaks all existing code which has already been written.

Also consider if you are using a pattern like MVVM. The current design means your view models can expose properties that are not tied to WPF in any way which ultimately makes your code more reusable across different technologies.

Finally, remember that there is a difference between the object that represents the property and they way that WPF renders that information. E.G. if you use a primitive type such as *System.String*, WPF will create a textblock and set the text property to the result of *ToString()*. This allows a very clean separation between the **data** that is displayed by the UI and they way the information is **rendered** by the UI.

Take a simple class that represents a menu item, for example:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

This type only exposes data about the menu item and has no information about how this information should be rendered. In fact, apart from the name of the class (*MenuItem*) this is not even specific to a menu item and the same data could be used in another UI control such as a checked listbox with no changes required. If the class exposed WPF specific user interface elements then the information would need to be adapted by another type for each different user interface control.